# Why does googlequicksearchbox use so much memory?

Tags: ram, 7.1-nougat

```
$ adb shell getprop | grep vendor.build.fingerprint
[ro.vendor.build.fingerprint]: [google/sailfish/sailfish:7.1.2/NJH47B/4021576:user/release-keys]

$ adb shell uname -a
Linux localhost 3.18.31-gc22ff6216f1a #1 SMP PREEMPT Tue Apr 11 18:11:27 UTC 2017 aarch64

$ adb shell dumpsys meminfo

Applications Memory Usage (in Kilobytes):
Uptime: 42779575 Realtime: 95413209

Total PSS by process:
    262,738K: com.google.android.googlequicksearchbox:search (pid 2648 / activities)
    224,188K: system (pid 1135)
    114,967K: com.android.systemui (pid 1570 / activities)
     88,623K: com.google.android.apps.nexuslauncher (pid 2742 / activities)
     73,651K: com.coffeemeetsbagel (pid 14865 / activities)
     72,482K: com.google.android.gms.persistent (pid 2404)
     70,038K: com.google.android.inputmethod.latin (pid 1525)
     55,043K: com.google.android.apps.maps (pid 5571)
     52,169K: com.google.android.gms (pid 3358)
```

Comment: More details, please. Maybe you should add some text description about the exact scenario, including how you configured Google Quick Search Box and what you've done with it.

Comment: I haven't done any configuration for Google Quick Search Box.   No pun intended, but I ran 'dumpsys meminfo' out-of-the-box